# delete session file after user removed the session cookie (like browser close)

Tags: php

I know that the session cookie will be removed automatically when the user closes his browser,

but in this way the session is lost, I mean that the session file in the /tmp directory is not deleted,
and it will remain in this directory forever, right?

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System will clean the /tmp directory automatically, you need not worry about that.

Comment: Look into PHP garbage collection, like http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php